# Use only 1 date from daily dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have a data set, which is a daily data set I want just to select 1 day as a month value, not the average or mean of the month. So I want to just use **2000131** to be in the data set and the same followed with all other months (last or second last date in the dataset). Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
    structure(list(X = 1:6, gvkey = c(7041L, 7041L, 7041L, 7041L, 
7041L, 7041L), datadate = c(20000103L, 20000104L, 20000105L, 
20000106L, 20000111L, 20000112L), cshoc = c(4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 
4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 4.2e+07, 4.2e+07), cshtrd = c(112000, 637000, 
241000, 251000, 224000, 194000), prccd = c(3.86, 4.28, 4, 4.04, 
4, 3.96), prchd = c(3.86, 4.6, 4.22, 4.26, 4.26, 4.04), prcld = c(3.3, 
3.86, 3.9, 3.96, 4, 3.9), prcstd = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L), qunit = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), cheqv = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), cheqvgross = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), div = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divd = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divdgross = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divdnet = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divdtm = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), divgross = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divnet = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divrc = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divrcgross = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divrcnet = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divsp = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divspgross = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divspnet = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), divsptm = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), anncdate = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), cheqvpaydate = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), divdpaydate = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), divrcpaydate = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), divsppaydate = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), paydate = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), recorddate = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), split = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), splitf = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), trfd = c(1.05474854, 1.05474854, 1.05474854, 
1.05474854, 1.05474854, 1.05474854), monthend = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), fyrc = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ggroup = c(2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), gind = c(201070L, 201070L, 
201070L, 201070L, 201070L, 201070L), gsector = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L), gsubind = c(20107010L, 20107010L, 20107010L, 
20107010L, 20107010L, 20107010L), naics = c(999990L, 999990L, 
999990L, 999990L, 999990L, 999990L), sic = c(9995L, 9995L, 9995L, 
9995L, 9995L, 9995L), spcindcd = c(400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 
400L), spcseccd = c(970L, 970L, 970L, 970L, 970L, 970L), ipodate = c(19920103L, 
19920103L, 19920103L, 19920103L, 19920103L, 19920103L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this :

Change the date values into actual date and extract year-month value from it. `arrange` the data based on `Date` and for each month select the last value of the month.

```
library(dplyr)

newdf3 <- newdata2 %>%
           mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(datadate), '%Y%m%d'),
                  month_year = format(Date, '%Y%m')) %>%
           arrange(desc(Date)) %>%
           group_by(gvkey, month_year) %>%
           slice(1L) %>%
           ungroup %>%
           arrange(gvkey)
```

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `datadate`.
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
i Input `datadate` is `as.Date(datadate, "%Y%m%d")`. @Ronak Shah

Comment: I have also mentioned the tags of the dataset. Kindly refer them.

Comment: ``library(dplyr)
newdata2 %>%
  mutate(datadate = as.Date(datadate, '%Y%m%d'), 
         month_year = format(datadate, '%Y%m')) %>%
  arrange(datadate) %>%
  group_by(month_year) %>%
 slice(1L)``

Comment: @NIrbhayMathur Pictures are not very good way to share data. Can you update your post with `dput(head(newdata2))` ?

Comment: You need to wrap `as.character` to `datadate` since it's a number. See updated answer if it helps.

Comment: now the problem is it is not stacked based on id. It shows in splited manner.

Comment: which is your id column? You can add `%>% ungroup %>% arrange(id_col_name)` to the above answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221431/discussion-between-nirbhay-mathur-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: newdf3<-newdata2 %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(datadate), '%Y%m%d'),
         month_year = format(Date, '%Y%m')) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date))%>%
  group_by(gvkey, month_year) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(gvkey)